# Set a form value using react-hook-form within React-Admin

Tags: react-hook-form, react-admin

In my React-Admin app, I'd like to leverage react-hook-form's [useFormContext](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext) for various things, such as, for example, setting the default pre-selected choice in this custom input field:

```
...
import { 
  Create, SimpleForm, SelectInput
} from 'react-admin';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyInput = () => {
  const formContext = useFormContext();
  formContext.setValue('category', 'tech');
  return (
    <SelectInput source="category" choices={[
        { id: 'tech', name: 'Tech' },
        { id: 'people', name: 'People' },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

...
const ItemCreate = () => {
  return (
    <Create>
      <SimpleForm>
        <MyInput />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
...
```

This sets the pre-selected value of the field, just as intended. But it throws a warning: `Cannot update a component ("Form") while rendering a different component ("MyInput")...`

Is there some way to achieve this without getting the warning?

Note: The only reason I'm using a custom input field here is because when I put `useFormContext()` directly into the component that contains SimpleForm it returns null (similarly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592559/formcontext-returns-null-inside-simpleform-on-local)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by moving `formContext.setValue` into a useEffect hook:

```
...
import { 
  Create, SimpleForm, SelectInput
} from 'react-admin';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyInput = () => {
  const formContext = useFormContext();

  // moved the setValue into a useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    formContext.setValue('category', 'tech');
  });

  return (
    <SelectInput source="category" choices={[
        { id: 'tech', name: 'Tech' },
        { id: 'people', name: 'People' },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

...
const ItemCreate = () => {
  return (
    <Create>
      <SimpleForm>
        <MyInput />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
...
```

Comment: It seems to me that with this usage, the value of the 'category' form field will always be 'tech'?

Comment: Yep, I think that's right. I just created this as a contrived example to demo the basic issue.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is related to the fact that the entire body of the `MyInput()` function is executed during each render, you need to call the `setValue()` function inside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got this working today using that exact approach.